# Segmentation fault issue

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a `system()` command to move the mouse using xdotool.

The following is my test program:

```
int main() {

    int x = 10;
    int y = 50;

    char* str;

    sprintf(str, "xdotool mousemove %d, %d", x, y);
    system(str);
}
```

I am getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.  Is there a way you know of to allow such a command to work?  I've tried it as root already by the way.  I'm new to c++ and your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I should point out that the mouse does indeed move.  However the segmentation fault occurs and that stops the program from running.  Perhaps there is a way to ignore the error?

Comment: It's always a very very *very* bad idea to ignore segfaults :)

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct however, you can use better methods in c++ rather than using `sprintf`

```
int main() {

   int x = 10;
   int y = 50;

   std::stringstream ss;
   ss <<  "xdotool mousemove " << x << " " << y;
   system(ss.str().c_str());
}
```

Comment: `ss.str().c_str()` is most likely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not assigning any space to print the string into.

For example you might want to do the following:

```
int main() {

    int x = 10;
    int y = 50;

    /* this assigns 255 characters of space for the string on the stack */
    char str[255];

    /* char* str -- this assigns no space, it just defines a pointer */

    /* this function will put the format string with arguments into the
     * space you provide... It will not provide it's own space. */
    sprintf(str, "xdotool mousemove %d, %d", x, y);
    system(str);
}
```

This will get rid of your seg fault because you are no longer accessing un-assigned memory.

Consider using [The c++ reference guide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) if you don't know how a function works.